# Неудачная попытка замены sass-rails на sassc-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass

Пытаюсь уйти от sass-rails, который deprecated с конца марта этого года... и вот что получаю.

Reproduce:

ruby 2.5.0p0 (2017-12-25 revision 61468) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
Rails 5.1.7
openSUSE Leap 15.0

1. Редактирую Gemfile, т.е. убираю `gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'` , пишу вместо него `gem 'sassc-rails'`
2. И далее:

   sudo gem uninstall sass-rails
   bundle
   git add .
   git commit -m "test"
   git remote add origin https://oauth2:xxxxxxxxx@gitlab.com/my_username/my_app.git
   git push -u origin master
   git clone https://oauth2:xxxxxxxxx@gitlab.com/my_username/my_app.git
   cd my_app/
   bundle install --path vendor/bundle
   rails s

Результат:

**Could not open library '/home/alex/my_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sassc-2.0.1/ext/libsass/lib/libsass.so': /home/alex/my_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sassc-2.0.1/ext/libsass/lib/libsass.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (LoadError)**

Т.е., если не пушить приложение, то после замены sass-rails на sassc-rails все работает (не понимаю, признаться). А вот клонированное с гитхаба/гитлаба приложение после описанных манипуляций - выдает эту ошибку. Был бы благодарен за ответ: кто-либо сталкивался с подобным? Идеи? - Вроде бы делаю все, как сказано в блоге разработчика гема, утверждающего, что достаточно заменить старый гем на новый в Gemfile.

Comment: У меня есть идея удалить Gemfile.lock, или выполнить `bundler update`.

Comment: Нет, суть проблемы в том, что эта либа - vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sassc-2.0.1/ext/libsass/lib/libsass.so - помещена разработчиком джема в гитигнор и, соответственно, исключена из гита. Но при клонировании проекта с гитхаба она не собирается, как должна бы. Соответственно, временный выход - добавить в гит принудительно.